# Flipping and mirroring an image multiple times on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a mosaic of and images clone that is flipped and mirrored agains each other.

But I can't get it to work properly. I have this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/arpo/yafLg7dc/

I want every second one flipped agains the first and so on.

But when I change to values to what I thought would do the trick the mosaic gets screwed up. Here's the values that I hoped should work but doesn't.

```
_drawImg(img, ctx, x1, y1, w, h, false, false);
_drawImg(img, ctx, x2, y1, w, h, true, false);
_drawImg(img, ctx, x1, y2, w, h, false, true);
_drawImg(img, ctx, x2, y2, w, h, true, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flipping an image horizontally (left to right) involves:**

- **translate** to the horizontal middle of the image. This sets the rotation point as the horizontal middle of the image. It does this by moving the canvas's [0,0] origin horizontally to the middle of the image.

  ```
  context.translate(x+img.width/2,0);
  ```
- Use **scale** to flip the image horizontally. This causes the image to be drawn as a horizontal mirror of itself.

  ```
  context.scale(-1,1);
  ```
- **drawImage** the image offset by half the image's width. This offset is necessary because `context.translate` has moved the [0,0] to the midpoint of the image so the image must be pulled leftward so that it's drawn at the desired X location.

  ```
  context.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,y);
  ```

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/car1.png";
function start(){
  drawImageExtended(img,50,50);
  drawImageExtended(img,50,92,true);
}

function drawImageExtended(img,x,y,flipHorizontally){
  if(flipHorizontally){
    ctx.translate(x+img.width/2,0);
    ctx.scale(-1,1);
    ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,y);
  }else{
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you!
Going mad on this canvas stuff! :)
I also found a solution to the problem. Updated my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/arpo/yafLg7dc/3/

Comment: @arpo. You're welcome. I checkout out your results fiddle and must say that's a very neat effect when your surfer image is mirrored. Good luck with your project!